# Как найти и убрать в JS vanila

Tags: javascript

В JS я пытаюсь найти в `li` нужный тег автора `data-author`, и когда они одинаковы с `idUser`, то убираем кнопку `#btn`. Чет то у меня не получается.

```
<span id="idUser" data-iduser="2"></span>

<ul>
  <li class="author author_id1" data-author="1" data-id="1">...</li>
    <li class="author author_id2" data-author="2" data-id="2">...</li>
    <li class="author author_id3" data-author="3" data-id="3">...</li>
</ul>

<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

```
const idUser = document.getElementById("idUser").dataset.iduser
const author = document.querySelectorAll('li').dataset.author
if (idUser === author) { 
    document.getElementById('btn').remove()
}
```

Как все это правильно дописать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('li')` возвращает коллекцию элементов, у неё нет свойства `.dataset.author`. Чтобы проверить, содержит ли какой-то элемент из этой коллекции свойство `.dataset.author`, совпадающее с `idUser`, можно превратить коллекцию в массив и воспользоваться методом [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
const idUser = document.getElementById("idUser").dataset.iduser
const authors = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')]

if (authors.some(author => author.dataset.author === idUser)) { 
    document.getElementById('btn').remove()
}
```

```html
<span id="idUser" data-iduser="2"></span>

<ul>
  <li class="author author_id1" data-author="1" data-id="1">...</li>
    <li class="author author_id2" data-author="2" data-id="2">...</li>
    <li class="author author_id3" data-author="3" data-id="3">...</li>
</ul>

<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: Заработало. Благодарю 